# Pagination not working perfect in php

Tags: php, jquery, pagination

I have create multi tab pagination like All,Popular,New tab.
in all tab i have insert code of pagination but when i have go Popular tab and page no 3 than i have go New tab but am not go there looking blanck page.

```
<?php
  $flag = $_GET['flag'];
  if(!isset($_GET['flag'])){
?>
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">All</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Popular</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">New</a></li>
<?php
  }
  elseif($flag == 3){
?>
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">All</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Popular</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">New</a></li>
<?php 
  }
  else if ($flag == 2) { 
?>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">All</a></li>
<li  ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Popular</a></li>
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">New</a></li>
<?php 
  }else { 
?>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">All</a></li>
<li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Popular</a></li>
<li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">New</a></li>
<?php   
  }
?>
<?php 
  $flag = $_GET['flag'];
  if($flag == 3){
?>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade in active">
<?php
  }
  else if(!isset($_GET['flag'])){
?>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade  in active">
<?php
  }else{
?>
<div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
<?php
  } 
?>
```

I have go in other tab then same page url show
like 
list.php?page=3&flag=3
if any tab go than show this url and page contant not show.
please help me.
Thank you

Comment: **Stop** using deprecates `mysql_*` API. Use `mysqli_` or `PDO with prepared statements.

Answer (score 0):

I Got answer
simply i have create java script function

```
              <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2" onclick="Redirect3();">All</a></li>
                                <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home" onclick="Redirect1();">Popular</a></li>
                                <li ><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1" onclick="Redirect2();">New</a></li>
```

and than

function Redirect1() {
               window.location="list.php?flag=1";
            }
            function Redirect2() {
               window.location="list.php?flag=2";
            }
            function Redirect3() {
               window.location="list.php?flag=3";
            }

it's working for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a pagination in bootstrap. It working fine. You have to only edit the query. Try it

```
<head>
    <link href="bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <script src="jquery.js"></script>
</head>
<?php

    //chage connection
    include_once("connection.php");
    //sql
    $sql = "SELECT COUNT(id) FROM records";

    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);
    $row = mysqli_fetch_row($query);
    $rows = $row[0];

    $page_rows = 2;

    $last = ceil($rows/$page_rows);
    if($last < 1)
    {
        $last = 1;
    }
    $pagenum = 1;
    if(isset($_GET['pn']))
    {
        $pagenum = preg_replace('#[^0-9]#', '', $_GET['pn']);
    }
    if ($pagenum < 1) 
    { 
        $pagenum = 1; 
    }
    else if ($pagenum > $last) 
    { 
        $pagenum = $last; 
    }
    $limit = 'LIMIT ' .($pagenum - 1) * $page_rows .',' .$page_rows;

    // $limit important, sql
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM records ORDER BY id DESC $limit";
    $query = mysqli_query($con, $sql);

    // This shows the user what page they are on, and the total number of pages
    $textline1 = "Data (<b>$rows</b>)";
    $textline2 = "Page <b>$pagenum</b> of <b>$last</b>";

    $paginationCtrls = '';

    if($last != 1)
    {       
    $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn=1">First</a></li>';

    if ($pagenum > 1) {
        $previous = $pagenum - 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$previous.'">Previous</a></li>';
        for($i = $pagenum-4; $i < $pagenum; $i++){
            if($i > 0){
                $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li class="disabled"><a href="">Previous</a></li>';
    }
    $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="" class="num-bg">'.$pagenum.'</a></li>';
    for($i = $pagenum+1; $i <= $last; $i++){
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$i.'">'.$i.'</a></li>';
        if($i >= $pagenum+4){
            break;
        }
    }
    if ($pagenum != $last) {
        $next = $pagenum + 1;
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$next.'">Next</a></li> ';
    }
    else
    {
        $paginationCtrls .= '<li class="disabled"><a href="">Next</a></li>';
    }

    $paginationCtrls .= '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'].'?pn='.$last.'">Last</a></li>';
}


//chage the loop
echo '<div class="container">';
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)){
    echo $row["id"];
    echo $row["name"];
    echo '<br><br>';
}

echo '</div>';
mysqli_close($con);
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
body{ font-family:"Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;}
.pagination li a:first-child
{
    border-radius:20px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div>
  <h2><?php echo $textline1; ?> Paged</h2>


  <center>

        <ul class="pagination"><?php echo $paginationCtrls; ?></ul>
        <p><?php echo $textline2; ?></p>
  </center>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<script>
    $(".num-bg").css({"background-color":"#A5D3FA","color":"white"});
</script>
```